# IIS 301 Redirect - Querystring handling

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7.5, query-string

I need to redirect requests in this format:

domain1.com/?page=example

to this format:

domain2.com/example

i.e. lose the "?page=" part.

How do I achieve this? At the moment we have hundreds of specific 301s in place, one for each page, but there must be a way of using one rule.

This is in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008

Comment: *URL Rewrite*: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks, I found the reference too - anyone able to give the specific syntax for this type of redirect?